# Facebook App Profile Tab is Empty ... No Content Displayed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I can view my application via the http://apps.facebook.com/myapplication/ link and the content shows up correctly. I also added the application as a tab to a facebook page. However, when viewing the tab no content is displayed.

I am using version 3 of the facebook toolkit for asp.net.

From what I've read this is caused by a redirect being caused to login. I used:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.RequireLogin = false;
```

But that doesn't fix the issue.

For debugging, I added a line to write to log file in the Page_Load and Page_PreInit. When viewing the app at http://apps.facebook.com/my_application/thepage.aspx a test string is written to the log at both Page_Load and Page_PreInit.

But when loading that same page (as a tab in a facebook page) nothing is written to the log file; as if Page_Load and Page_PreInit isn't being hit.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out facebook wants a / at the end of the canvas URL. Otherwise the relative links wont't work.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Tab Pages for a Facebook Page only supports FBML applications not iframe.

Is your application iframe?